# Change trailing character in all numbered lists in a large document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been trying to change several numbered lists in a large document using vba. I want to change the trailing character from tab to space. Below is the code I am using without success. There are other bulleted lists at the same document.

```
Public Sub test2b()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim curList As List, curPar As Paragraph, templ As ListTemplate
    Dim gapSize As Double, level As Integer, rtext As String

    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Lists.Count
        Set curList = ActiveDocument.Lists(i)
        Debug.Print "i ", i
        For n = 1 To curList.ListParagraphs.Count
            Debug.Print "n ", n
            Set curPar = curList.ListParagraphs(n)
            Set templ = curPar.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate
            level = curPar.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
            gapSize = templ.ListLevels(level).TextPosition - templ.ListLevels(level).NumberPosition
            templ.TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingSpace
        Next n
        UndoClear
        Set curList = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: why don't you just do a find/replace on vbtab,vbcrlf and replace with ' ', vbcrlf

Comment: In a well-constructed Word document, the numbered lists will be formatted with a _List Style_. You can update the list style and all instances of the style will immediately be updated. No VBA required. Here's an article on how to construct list styles, it may help with revising the styles you have: https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768

Comment: The initial work is about 120 MS-Word documents, with an average of 60 pages, converted from PDF, whose process generated a large amount of trailing tabs numbered lists.
Now it's a preparation process for exporting the paragraphs to MySQL database, including formatting. And after those, if all goes well, there will be periodic additions.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I had already briefly seen this article and disregarded it. But, because of your recommendation, I'll reread it with less haste.

Comment: I managed to find a solution by changing to templ.ListLevels(level).TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingSpace